# adding both equal and not equal conditions in Yii

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, equals-operator

```
$id = Yii::app()->user->getState("logId");
$name = Yii::app()->user->getState("username"); 

$dataProvider=Disnotification::model->findAllByAttributes(array('logID' => $id,'username'!=$name));
```

How can I find records which equals to `$id` but not equals to `$name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = "username != '$name' AND logID = :id";
$criteria->params = array (
    ':id' => $id,
);
$dataProvider = Disnotification::model()->findAll( $criteria );
```

Comment: Thanks .it worked.But you should remove the ' ' from $id. Otherwise it won't work.Hope it is a mistake. (':id' => $id)

Answer (score 3):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->compare('logID' , $id);
$criteria->addCondition('username != :username');
$criteria->params[ ':username' ] = $name;

$dataProvider = Disnotification::model()->findAll( $criteria );
```

Comment: dear sir, It is givving an error saying CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.

Comment: I updated my answer, @user3894236 did you find what you've been looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dataProvider = Disnotification::model() -> findAllByAttributes(
        array(
            'logId'=>$id,
        ),
        new CDbCriteria(
            array(
                'order'=>'x ASC, y DESC',
                'condition'=>'username<>'.$username,
            ))
    );
```